# Regex for example 22,123456

Tags: regex

Somebody know regex for two numbers, (comma) and then 6 numbers after comma. For example 22,123456. Somebody here who can help me?

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Say, looking up a regex tutorial?

Comment: if you just tried googling it, you could have got so many explanations.

Answer (score 1):

This should match any decimal number:

```
/\d+,\d+/
```

Comment: ... which is more than the asker asked for.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I used \d{2}[,]\d{6}

Comment: Although that works for the above example it won't if your number is 222,897

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/\d+\.\d{6}/
/\d{2}\.\d{6}/
```

Or this if you wil use comma:

```
/\d+,\d{6}/
/\d{2},\d{6}/
```

Example: [here](http://regex101.com/r/jY2bD0)

Comment: Thanks buddy! I used \d{2}[,]\d{6}

Answer (score 1):

You may like this:-

```
\d{2},\d{6}
```

Explanation:-

```
\d{2} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: Exactly 2 times
, matches the character , literally
\d{6} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: Exactly 6 times
```

Comment: Thanks dude! It worked! I used \d{2}[,]\d{6}

Comment: @user3351244:- Although I used `[]` brackets initially in my answer but you can ignore that. It will work too ;)

Answer (score 0):

and two numbers before comma and six after:

```
/\d{2}\,\d{6}/
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit strictly to 2 digits, a comma, 6 digits:

```
^\d\d,\d{6}$
```

where

```
^    : match the begining of the string<br>
\d\d : 2 digits
,    : a comma
\d{6}: 6 digits
$    : end of the string
```

or, if the number is in the middle of a string:

```
\b\d\d,\d{6}\b
```

`\b` is a word boundary, it assumes there're no digits before and after.